# Animation is not working when I try to move the images

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I always see 'can not read properties of null' in the console. I couldn't find the problem. It was supposed to animate the images according to the cursor. I tried to do it with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkADl0HubMY)

It should have slide with the cursor like in this website https://camillemormal.com/ but it always says can not read properties of null.

```js
const yol = document.getElementById("resim-yolu");

// mouse tıklama fonksiyonu
window.onmousedown = e => yol.dataset.mouseDownAt = e.clientX;

// her mouse komutu bittiğinde imlecin kaldığı yeri depolamalıyız
window.onmouseup = () => {
  yol.dataset.mouseDownAt = "0";
  yol.dataset.oncekiYuzde = yol.dataset.yuzde;
}

window.onmousemove = e => {

  // mouse ile komut verildiğini anlamak için
  if (yol.dataset.mouseDownAt === "0") return;

  // İmlecin geldiği konumu bilmek için başlanguç noktasından şu anki konumu çıkartıyoruz.
  const mouseDelta = parseFloat(yol.dataset.mouseDownAt) - e.clientX,

    // makismum uzaklık bulunduğumuz pencerenin yarısı kadar.  
    maxDelta = window.innerWidth / 2;

  // mousedelta ve maxdeltanın bölümü decimal bir rakam verir ve 100le çarpımı yüzde olarak hesaplamamızı sağlar. 
  const yuzde = (mouseDelta / maxDelta) * -100,

    // yüzde için 0 değişkeni oluşturuldu ve yüzdelik kaymayı son kayma oranına ekelyerek yeni yüzdeyi bulduk. Bu şekilde mouse komutu bırakıldığında işlem başa dönmeyecek.
    yeniYuzde = parseFloat(yol.dataset.oncekiYuzde) + yuzde,
    oncekiYuzde = Math.max(Math.min(yeniYuzde, 0), -100);

  yol.dataset.yuzde = yeniYuzde;

  yol.animate({
    transform: `translate(${yeniYuzde}%, -50%)`
  }, {
    duration: 1200,
    fill: "forwards"
  })
}

for (const img of yol.getElementsByClassName("img")) {
  img.animate({
    objectPosition: `${yeniYuzde + 100}% center`
  }, {
    duration: 1200,
    fill: "forwards"
  })
}
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#resim-yolu>.img {
  width: 40vmin;
  height: 56vmin;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 100% center;
}

#resim-yolu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4vmin;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="resim-yolu" data-mouse-down-at="0" data-prev-yuzde="0">
  <img class="img" src="work.jpg" alt="work" draggable="false">
  <img class="img" src="university.jpg" alt="university" draggable="false">
  <img class="img" src="university.jpg" alt="university" draggable="false">
  <img class="img" src="university.jpg" alt="university" draggable="false">
  <img class="img" src="university.jpg" alt="university" draggable="false">
  <img class="img" src="university.jpg" alt="university" draggable="false">
  <img class="img" src="university.jpg" alt="university" draggable="false">
</div>
```

Comment: The error is because your JS syntax is invalid - you've got a `}` in the wrong place. This is what the JS code structure should be: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ye84cjon/. Note that this still doesn't do anything with your images, though, but at least the error is gone. Your question isn't very clear on what your goal is - simply linking to a site saying 'it supposed to do this' isn't very helpful.